# How do i handle heavy page loads with php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have a script that generates xml of products on users webstores. Now, this xml needs to be read from the browser into mysql database using php. The issue is that, sometimes the size of the xml is such large in (MegaBytes) that

1. it does not print on the user's site even though it is constructed
2. does not get passed due to its weight and server time outs with the browser.

I learned these remedies may help.

1. Increasing the CPU of the machine i use to access and parse the xml
2. Increasing the cache of the the browser

I have done all these but still cannot get it effective. Any other solutions out there?

Comment: maybe uploading this file to the server may help?

Comment: so you have two scripts, one generates the xml and the other one reads that xml through HTTP and then inserts into database? where do you get timeout? What is the size of xml?

Comment: the timeouts happen in generating the xml and sometimes parsing. but mainly in the xml generation. the size sometimes can be about 20MB

Comment: @k102: pls explain further. the problrm really is in the generation of the xml. It takes loong and breaks due to time outs.

Comment: sorry, i thougth the problem is in parsing this file. can you show the generation script?

Comment: @k102: the generation script might not be quite helpful now. It's a completely new thing. It connects to a user's db and creates xml out of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use XML to transfer large amounts of data from one server to another. Try [this link about mysqldump](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/mysql/mysqlbackup/mysqldump.html).

If you must use XML to exchange the data, consider compressing it to reduce the XML-dump's size.

You could also try not to transfer the whole product list at ones, but in chunks of maybe 100 products.

Can you explain how a browser is related to this problem? Do you call the XML-generating script in your browser by hand and then send the XML to a second server?

Comment: Also consider zipping a XML file in server side

Comment: "consider compressing" yes. zip, gzip, rar, deflate, bzip2, ...

Comment: @Basti: thanks. The link to the xml lies in the client's server. Now, i have to read the link and parse it. Since XML is mark up, it needs to get printed on the browser before i can save or parse it. So my parsing browser should have a good cache, CPU mgt in order to read all data.

Comment: you don't have to display XML in a browser to import it into your database. you can have your server fetch the xml data directly (file_get_contents($uri)), parse it (for instance with http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php ) and import it in one run.

Comment: browsers are generally not made to display large amounts of mark up like 70MB xml-databases. having a browser display a 70MB html/xml-file can take forever whereas having a server parse and import the same file could only take seconds.

Comment: @Basti: thats a good input. i'm researching on it now.

Answer (score 0):

20MB is not that big. To solve timeouts while generating or parsing xml try to increase time limit, for example:

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

will set time limit to 5 minutes.

If it is not enough then look at your scripts they are probably need optimisation.

Comment: yeah, i've increased that too. but as you said, it has to do with optimization.

Comment: there are other files as big as 70MB

Comment: what kind of timeouts do you get? can you copy/paste error messages here?

Comment: it does not really print out, but it hangs. meaning, the xml printing takes up much memory in the browser and cache.